# Can I use jQuery in a matched Children

Tags: jquery, hover, children

I try to do some slide in/out a Child element of each Grid item.

I tried to handle the $.target.children[0] as an jQuery element to use `.show()` and `.hide()`  for example.

```
 /*--------- Product Card Overlay -------------------------------------*/

   $(".products-grid").children().hover(function ($) {

       /*------ MOUSE IN --------*/

       match an animate in the child element (div.overlay)

   }, function () {

       /*------ MOUSE OUT --------*/
       match an animate out the child element (div.overlay)
   });

/*--------- /Product Card Overlay ----------------------------------*/
```

Actually I stuck and my brain crashed. Can anybody give me a hint at the right way?

Comment: Where is your actual code that attempts to do this? You said you tried to handle `$.target.children[0]`, so show that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you. Notice how first item has `display:none`, that is if you need to have the overlay initially hidden.

You could use `.toggleClass()` with an `.active` class instead of `.toggle()` if you are more confortable with doing the animation in css.

Hope this helps!

```css
.products-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.products-grid .product {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  max-width: 35%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 7.5px 15px 7.5px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.products-grid .product .prod-details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: top .3s ease, opacity .3s ease;
}
.products-grid .product:hover .prod-details {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-grid">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="prod-details"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. I didnt work with css flex until yet but I can learn something about it yet. But is it possible to fade the overlay-div in and slide the content-div of the overlay from bottom to top by hovering over the grid item via css or do I need JavaScript/jQuery for it?

Comment: Actually you can do it via css only. I will edit my answer to match your needs!

Comment: There you go, i modified my answer's snippet to have no javascript/jQuery. Hope this will help.